# How to get rid of ifdef's in a large c project

Tags: c, visual-c++, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I got my hands on a opensource project coded in **C**. It uses #ifdef's for cross-compiling. There are a lot of ifdef's all over the source code. I want just to modify it for one platform. I was thinking to run it through compiler's pre-processor (Visual C++) but it will write the preprocessed result to a single file, which I don't need. Anybody knows a way to pre-process a project leaving it's structure intact (all files intact)? No grep, please.

### edit:

I found a potential solution (it's amazing what you can find on the internet these days). It's boost.wave - a C++ preprocessor library which can do some interesting stuff. I don't know how it will turn out, but I will give it a try. Still, it's not the final answer, so if you have a solution then I will be glad to hear it.

Comment: why would you want to do this? readability? why not just let the #ifdefs remain so that if you ever want to share your modification, it will still crosscompile.

Comment: @j-a i counted 250 ifdef's in the main.c file. It's really a problem to me understanding all what's going on. Plus i want to add only platform specific code to the project.

Comment: Why are we not allowed to use regexp?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan where's the challenge with regexen?

Comment: I had the perfect solution in mind, until I read your last sentence.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No grep on windows, and i have a lot of software installed so going for Cygwin or mingw will be a pain. Plus, it will be nice to use some compiler wisdom.

Comment: If the project is not too big, commenting out the `#include`s and preprocessing the individual files could be an option.

Comment: Does visual-c++ have an option similar to gcc's -fdirectives-only?

Comment: @RichardPennington i think it doesn't.

Comment: There's grep on my system. And Perl. And Python. How does anyone get anything done without these basic tools?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have python too, but in the project are also imbricated ifdef's and elseif's. I don't want to write a c compiler in python. I'll see, if nobody knows a way then i'll have to use grep, or even manually go over source.

Comment: Would this possibly be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998913/visual-studio-hiding-ifdef-blocks

Comment: @DanFego Yes, it is. I'll try to see if it works in VS2010.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two tools I know of that you could use to do this semi-automatically.

One is [`sunifdef`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sunifdef/) (son of `unifdef`).  AFAIK, this is no longer being maintained, though (and neither is `unifdef` on which it is based).

The other is [`coan`](http://coan2.sourceforge.net/index.php), which is being actively maintained, and is a development of `sunifdef`.

See also: [Is there a C pre-processor which eliminates `#ifdef` blocks based on values defined/undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525283/is-there-a-c-pre-processor-which-eliminates-ifdef-blocks-based-on-values-define).

As it happens, I'm still using `sunifdef` on the main project at work where I'm eliminating archaic code (for example, machines not supported since about 1996) from the code base.  The only gotcha I have with it is that if a line goes in with parentheses like this:

```
#if (defined(MACH_A) && defined(PROP_P)) || (defined(MACH_B) && defined(PROP_Q)) || \
    (defined(MACH_C) && defined(PROP_R))
```

and we have `-UMACH_C` (so machine C is no longer supported), the output line is:

```
#if defined(MACH_A) && defined(PROP_P) || defined(MACH_B) && defined(PROP_Q)
```

Technically, that's fine; it is correct.  It is just preferable to keep the extra, technically redundant parentheses in the expression.

One caveat: although I can answer for these compiling on Unix-based systems, I've not personally checked them out on Windows.

Comment: It's nice that there is a tool. Since it works, i can set up a Linux VM to clean the code.

Comment: I was checking the website, and i found that the windows 7 is supported too(even 64bit).

Answer (score 3):

Comment out/remove the #include directives, preprocess it, reinstate the includes.

You'll need to make sure any macros used by the #ifdef are available, of course.

Comment: Nice. I'll remember this technique for dealing with single files.