# Preprocessing of C/C++ metaprograms

Tags: c++, c, metaprogramming

We have a large C++ project and would like to ship only the code that a customer asks for, thus removing all code that is not needed. I.e. if we have some metaprograms like:

```
/** File: calc.c */
#ifdef ENABLE_SOME_ADVANCED_FEATURE
/** Advanced calculations */
void AdvancedCalc(int a, int b) {
   // ...
}
#else
/** Basic calculations */
void BasicCalc(int a, int b) {
   // ...
}
#endif
```

I would like some script that does preprocessing of C++ metaprograms, thus if I only wanted the basic calculations after running the script the file would look like this:

```
/** File: calc.min.c */
/** Basic calculations */
void BasicCalc(int a, int b) {
   // ...
}
```

Thus, all the code we did not want to ship has been stripped away.

I'm sure there must be something like this out there.

**Update:**

I think [How to get rid of ifdef's in a large c project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679350/how-to-get-rid-of-ifdefs-in-a-large-c-project) has the solution I was looking for.

Comment: Doesn't the c++ preprocessor do this already? I don't understand what you're after.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the one downside is that the code will probably be completely unreadable afterwards. And all included headers will be in one file.

Comment: If I understand the question you want to preprocess the file but only on certain parts, that is only on specific lines such as `#ifdef ENABLE_FOO` but not on others such as `#include <foo.h>`. Also see this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713336/run-preprocessor-only-but-with-only-for-certain-statements

One idea there is to comment out the preprocessor lines you don't want expanded, then to run `gcc -E`, then to un-comment out the preprocessor lines that you commented out in the first step

Comment: Do you ship the *source code* to the customer or the *compiled binary*?

Comment: @RedX OK I see! Didn't catch the OP's going to ship the source code. I'd try to write a text processing script to do this, catching balanced `#if`/`#else`/'#endif` blocks isn't that hard.

Comment: @Brandin i think `gcc -E` strips out all the comments.

Comment: I too think that this can be done in `python` in about an hour.

Comment: Boost has a program called `bcp` that does similar. If you want *only* the Boost `shared_ptr` stuff, then you would use `bcp` to copy out only what was needed. But it works at the source-file level, and not a preprocessor-level.

Comment: @Vorac Yup! Looks like I have to fire up the old parser and make something myself :P

Comment: @IngeHenriksen, great! If you boss allows it, please post the code here afterwords. You will get quite some upvotes :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get rid of ifdef's in a large c project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679350/how-to-get-rid-of-ifdefs-in-a-large-c-project)

Answer (score 1):

**Clang or G++**

```
g++ -E source.cpp
```

> -E  Stop after the preprocessing stage; do not run the compiler
>   proper.  The output is in the form of preprocessed source code, which
>   is sent to the standard output.
>
> Input files that don't require preprocessing are ignored.

**Visual Studio**

*preprocessor output to stdout*

```
cl /E source.cpp
```

*preprocessor output to file*

```
cl /P source.cpp
```

**Example of how to cut down the unwanted output (ignore-header.pl)**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

while (my $line = <>) {

    if ($line !~ /^#include/) {
        print $line
    }
}
```

**Execute**

> cat source.cpp | perl ignore-headers.pl | g++ -E -nostdinc -nostdinc++ -x c++ -

**Resources**

[G++ Manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/g++)

[Visual Stuido Manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6.aspx)

[GCC preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917316/gcc-preprocessor)

Comment: Thanks, but sadly the `-E` compiler outputs a lot of "garbage" that I don't want in my source, example here: http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_36.html , removes my `#include` directives etc. so it's not optimal for my use case. I don't want any of the code rewritten but just remove what's not inside the desired `#define` blocks. I tried your solution with the Intel C++ compiler too but encountered the same problem.

Comment: Are yee not a developer? I've updated my answer with an example that will cut down the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GCC preprocessor

```
gcc -E
```

See [GCC preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917316/gcc-preprocessor)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this would output everything I compile to stdout as one big stream - I was rather expecting a single file like in my example. It also outputs a lot of "garbage", see here http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_36.html for an example of what I mean by "garbage".

Answer (score 0):

`gcc -E filename` should do the trick 
[GCC Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html)

Comment: How is this answer better than the whole bunch that were given 10 minutes or more before?

Comment: Well, I don't think the OP wants the #include-directives to be evaluated (which is done by -E)?

Comment: This is a better answer than @synapse as I can do control the compiler output, but it still outputs a lot of "garbage" that I don't want in my source: http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_36.html and removes my `#include` directives etc. so it's not optimal for my use case. I don't want any of the code rewritten but just remove what's not inside the desired `#define` blocks. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Several options:

1. You can use `gcc -E` like others suggest, but you can also add the `-H` flag to get a file listing.

   2 . You could just do your compilation with `-MD`, and `.d` files will be generated.  You can either process .d files with a script or better yet you can probably create a rule to zip up all dependencies as part of your compile.
2. I would also look to see how debuginfo packages are generated as they drop sources in /usr/src/debug  (at least in the RPM ecosystem)

Answer (score 0):

I'd prepare a script that:

- comment-out all the includes and the defines that must not be touched, with some "magic wildcard", like `//@TAKE_ME_BACK@` and save it to a temporary file;
- run `cpp -C` or whatever preprocessor on the temporary file (`cpp -C` has the advantage that the file doesn't need to terminate with .c). Important: it must not strip comments (that's the `-C` for)!
- uncomment-in all the lines previously commented out, restoring your includes

If you need to deal with recursive `#ifdef`'s, I think that awk range syntax (pattern1,pattern2) could be of great help.

On the other side, if you just need to ignore includes, something like this will do the job:

```
sed 's|^#include|//@TAKE_ME_BACK@#include|' $file > $file.tmp
cpp -C $file.tmp > $file.tmp2
sed -e '/^#/d' -e 's|//@TAKE_ME_BACK@||' < $file.tmp2 > $file
```

(you need to take care also of the lines beginning with `#` dropped by the preprocessor in the last sed).

Note1: in the example I that I have proposed **the original file is overwritten**: handle with care :)

Note2: working but not tested - just a suggestion to be elaborated/customized.